# adding the anonymous_user_required to register view in flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm trying to find out if there is a reason that the @anonymous_user_required decorator is not put onto the /register route by default in flask-security. If there is no good reason, what is the best way add this decorator to the route from my own application without modifying the flask-security source code?